# Laravel file upload from modal is returning blank

Tags: laravel

i have created a modal for file uploading, this is a client request, so i need to do it this way, i have already this:

```
{{-- Single Take Photo modal --}}
    <div class="modal modal-success fade" tabindex="-1" id="takephoto_modal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="{{ __('voyager::generic.close') }}"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="voyager-photo"></i> Tomar Foto</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <form action="#" id="takephoto_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" files="true">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <input type='file' accept="image/x-png, image/jpeg" capture="camera"/>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="Tomar Foto">
                    </form>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">{{ __('voyager::generic.cancel') }}</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Now, the js:

```
$('td').on('click', '.takephoto', function (e) {
            $('#takephoto_form')[0].action = '{{ route('voyager.'.$dataType->slug.'.submitphoto', ['id' => '__id']) }}'.replace('__id', $(this).data('id'));
            $('#takephoto_modal').modal('show');
        });
```

And the function in controller:

```
// POST
        public function submitPhoto(Request $request, $id)
        {
            $input = Input::all();
            dd($input);
            die();
        }
```

Ok, everything is working, the js is taking the action to the function, and sending the id so i can update then the db, this is an edit function, this is what im getting, no files , 
Im using Laravel Voyager, its Laravel...so i can use any Laravel class.

Answer (score 1):

Already fixed by adding an id on html:

```
<input type='file' accept="image/x-png, image/jpeg" name="photo" id="photo" capture="camera"/>
```

Then you can do `$request->hasFile('photo');`